# number of instruments GMM estimator in R

Tags: dynamic, panel, gmm

I have one question, maybe very simple. In Stata in dynamic panel data model (GMM estimator) you recieve a "number of instruments". In turn, in R you recieve AR test, sargan test but the "number of instruments" is nor displayed. How to obtain number of isntruments in R?
Thank you for helping

Comment: Could you give an example of code you're using in your question (edit the question)? Knowing which library and/or function may help someone find an answer for you.

Comment: This is my model (dynamic panel data model):

Comment: pgmm(formula = per.cap ~ P1 + invest + educ3, data = testdat, 
    effect = "twoways", model = "twosteps", ... = list(lag.form = list(1, 
        0, 0, 0), gmm.inst = ~per.cap, lag.gmm = list(c(2:99))))

Comment: lag(per.cap, 1)  0.766586   0.217325  3.5274 0.0004197 ***
P1              -0.997391   0.522269 -1.9097 0.0561688 .  
invest           0.041296   0.185683  0.2224 0.8240026    
educ3            0.072270   0.269289  0.2684 0.7884131    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Sargan Test: chisq(5) = 11.33552 (p.value=0.045119)
Autocorrelation test (1): normal = 0.4150361 (p.value=0.67812)
Autocorrelation test (2): normal = 0.1294214 (p.value=0.89702)
Wald test for coefficients: chisq(4) = 23.01949 (p.value=0.0001255)

Comment: You need to put your code into your original question, preferably into a code block, or people are less likely to help.

Comment: but I don't find number of instruments ,

Comment: I dont know why R does not display the number of instruments. In Stata or Gretl this information is displayed,

Answer (score 0):

If you used all the 99 lags available for the instrumental variable, the number of instruments (for each instrumental variable) will be:
(0,5 x t-1 x t-2) + the number of time dummies you used.

(t is the time span of your data).

If you used less the all available lags, I don’t know how to calculate the number of instruments. If someone knows, please tell me!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).